# How to create all substrings starting from the first letter?

Tags: regex

How do I create a regular expression that has the following result:

Input: `apple`

Output: `a,ap,app,appl,apple`

I was given this “[^”]+"|([^)]+)|[^"\s()]+ but it doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to have the output an array of text and I need to use regular expression.

Comment: This is solvable by a simple loop. What does this have to do with regexes? What have you tried?

Comment: What language ?

Comment: I was given this “[^”]+"|([^)]+)|[^"\s()]+ but it doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to have the output an array of text and I need to use regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two simple nested loops should suffice and code structure should be more or less similar in all languages:

```js
str=`apple`;

for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++)
{
  tmp="";
  for(var j=0;j<=i;j++)
      tmp+=str[j];
  console.log(tmp);
}
```

This is a bit weird if you have to solve it by using regex but this can be done with the help of regex :

```js
str=`apple`;
finalStr=str.split("").reverse().join("");
var result=[];
const regex = /.(?=(.*))/g;
let m;
while ((m = regex.exec(finalStr))!== null) 
  result.push((m[0]+m[1]).split("").reverse().join(""));
  
result=result.reverse();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I was given this “[^”]+"|([^)]+)|[^"\s()]+ but it doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to have the output an array of text and I need to use regular expression.